# LinkedIn PBI Custom Data Connector - Error when scheduling a report refresh

Tags: powerbi, linkedin-api, powerbi-gateway, powerbi-custom-data-connector

Such as to report on a company's LinkedIn page from Power Bi, I created a LinkedIn app, with the required scope (using the Marketing Developer Platform product), and developed my own custom data connector to access the API.

I don't have any issue retrieving the data in Power BI, and publishing the report. Such as to be able to schedule a refresh, I configured a personal gateway for this data connector. When adding my credential in dataset settings, I get the following error:

"Failed to update data source credentials: No contracts are associated with the logged in account, or the user does not have reporting permission on any contracts."

Has any one encountered this error before, or would know how I can solve it/ what contract does it refer to? My guess for now is that Linkedin only allow this kind of access for people who have a Sales Navigator account?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing the personal gateway by a normal one solved the issue.